# Execute task before Android Gradle build?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

is it possible for Gradle to execute a task before calling

```sh
gradle build
```

Something like `precompile`. Someone please help. Is something like this possible and how?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
task build << {
    println 'build'
}
task preBuild << {
    println 'do it before build'
}
build.dependsOn preBuild
```

Thanks to that task `preBuild` will be automatically called before `build` task.

If you want to run `preBuild` in configuration phase (previous example run `preBuild` in `execution` phase) you can do it in this way:

```
task build << {
    println 'build'
}
build.doFirst {
    println 'do it before build'
}
```

More about gradle build lifecycle can be read here http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html.

Comment: how to execute batch file after APK is generated at this location "\app\build\outputs\apk" ? My requirement is like once xyz.apk generated at "\app\build\outputs\apk" location I want to move this file to "D:/Xyz" location automatically.

Comment: The explanation for the second example is wrong. `doFirst` will add the closure as the first task action for the build task. Task actions are executed in the execution phase.

Comment: The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

Comment: got an error: `Could not get unknown property 'preBuild' for root project` in Android Studio 3.1.3. Could you show me the complete gradle files?

Comment: Can I call this let's say before a `gradlew assemble` task and if so how?

Comment: Is there a way to write this using the `java` api instead of groovy? I am asking because I am developing a gradle plugin that should run `kapt{variantName}kotlin` task to process some annotations before a build happens. I have tried `dependsOn` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 37):

For those who are wondering how to do this in an Android project, this worked for me:

```
task myTask << {
  println "here's a task"
}
preBuild.dependsOn myTask
```

Comment: Is it possible to call this before `assembleDebug`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky check please my answer above how to this

Answer (score 13):

There is one more way how to do this

```
task myTask << {
    println "here's a task"
}
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
    task.dependsOn myTask 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this for the `preBuild` task but it doesn't seem to be taking.

Comment: It doesn't seem that preBuild actually comes through `whenTaskAdded`. I don't see it when I print the `task.name` in this closure.

Comment: `if (task.name == 'preDebugBuild' || task.name == 'preReleaseBuild')` works for me instead of `preBuild`.

Comment: @atreat What is your question?

Comment: Sorry not really a question. just a spew of ramblings. For future-readers, the `whenTaskAdded` mechanism does not seem to work for the `preBuild` task. It seems this task does not invoke this closure. I used the above examples to define dependents on `preBuild`, but used `whenTaskAdded` to add dependents on other tasks, such as `validateReleaseSigning`.

Answer (score 8):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
tasks.register/* OR .create */("MyTask") {
    doLast {
        println("I am the task MyTask")
    }
}

tasks.build {
    dependsOn("MyTask")
}

// OR another notation
// tasks.named("build") {
//     dependsOn(tasks["MyTask"])
// }
```

For more information see [Gradle documentation: Adding dependencies to a task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks).

Answer (score 4):

The left shift operator `<<` was removed in Gradle 5.

In my case I had an Android project using a Java sub project and this worked:

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        println 'do it before build'
    }
}

assemble.dependsOn myTask
```

Regarding the initial question this should be the syntax now:

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        println 'do it before build'
    }
}
build.dependsOn myTask
// or for Android
preBuild.dependsOn myTask
```

Comment: This gives me this error in gradle 7.2: `could not get unknown property 'build' for root project 'core' of type org.gradle.api.Project`

Comment: @alex-spurling What is the name of the gradle file? Is it `build.gradle`? Is defining `defaultTasks 'build' help?

Comment: Yes, the name of the gradle file is `build.gradle` and no, adding `defaultTasks 'build'` in my build file does not help.

Comment: With lower versions it works? Maybe some different build plugins are used or the order of the inclusion is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

In Gradle 5.4.x

```
// File: app/build.gradle
// See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html
task ruby(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '../'
    executable = '/usr/bin/env'
    args = ["ruby", "--version"]
}
preBuild.dependsOn ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

If the task to be run is already defined (for example `publishToMavenLocal`), you can add it into your `gradle build` task with:

```
build.dependsOn publishToMavenLocal
```