# Detect Android deployment target from Gradle build file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

I'm looking to extend my gradle build with a call to an external tool.  The issue is that I need to provide the current CPU architecture that is currently being targeted, for example `armeabi` or `arm64-v8a` if the user has chosen to deploy to a physical device.  I am having trouble finding a way of determining this information in the gradle build file.

Currently I am performing this action in a custom task which runs before preBuild, similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532415/execute-task-before-android-gradle-build).  Is there any way to detect the CPU architecture at this point?

```
task customTask(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "myTool.exe", "-architecture=$something"
}

preBuild.dependsOn customTask
```

I'm using the [experimental plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) 0.7.0-beta3.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the CPU architecture (ABI) of the connected device with an ADB shell command:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```

For a Nexus 5 this would return `armeabi-v7a` as an example.

Now we have to wrap that command into a gradle method:

```
def getDeviceAbi() {
    return "adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi".execute().text.trim()
}
```

Then you can simply call this method from your task:

```
task customTask(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "myTool.exe", "-architecture=" + getDeviceAbi()
}
preBuild.dependsOn customTask
```