# How do I get gradle to run a task before building?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

I am working with an ndk project using gradle-experimental. I have a "prebuilt" library that is really a library I generate with a shell call in a gradle task. I am trying to make it very easy for this project to run out of the box, so I need to be able to run this buildTask before gradle builds. I have looked into `preBuild.dependsOn ...`, but unfortunately, that is not supported in experimental. Any ideas? I currently have a `.sh` file that runs it, but I'm trying to get away from it.

Edit: Not duplicate because gradle-experimental doesn't support preBuild as I already stated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execute task before android gradle build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532415/execute-task-before-android-gradle-build)

Comment: Except this is in gradle-experimental. Please read the differences and what I wrote.

Answer (score -1):

Assumptions:

- NDK `moduleName` is ***foo***
- Supported `ABI` is ***armeabi***
- `Variants` are ***debug*** and ***release***

You'll have to create a combination for every variant and ABI you added to the abiFilters.

Create a RuleSource class in `build.gradle`

```
class FooRuleSource extends RuleSource {

    @Mutate
    void validatePreCompileFooDebugEnvironmentArmeabi(
        @Path('tasks.compileFooArmeabiDebugSharedLibraryFooMainCpp') Task compileTask) {
        validateEnvironment(compileTask)
    }

    @Mutate
    void validatePreCompileFooReleaseEnvironmentArmeabi(
        @Path('tasks.compileFooArmeabiReleaseSharedLibraryFooMainCpp') Task compileTask) {
        validateEnvironment(compileTask)
    }

    private void validateEnvironment(compileTask) {
        compileTask.dependsOn("desiredTask")
    }

}
```

Create the task in your `build.gradle`:

```
task desiredTask(type:Exec){
    commandLine 'echo', 'hi'
}
```