# Get compile time in react-native?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to get the compile time (time at which i compiled the app, e.g. in utc or local). The reason I want this is that I often am not sure what version my emulator is running right now and adding a text widget at the top with the compile time would give me this security while developing.

Answer (score 1):

One way I would do that :

1. make a shell script that runs before build, and gets current system time
   (for iOS, this can be done adding a script phase before your build phases, on android, you need to change your gradle, see : [execute task before android gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532415/execute-task-before-android-gradle-build))
2. Inject that time into a .env file, then use [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) to recover this 'buildTime' variable and display it.

There must be other ways to do that, but no ready-to-use tool to my knownledge, you will have to dive into Platforms specific build scripts ...

Comment: thanks was hopeing to avoid this somehow^^ but thanks

Comment: Personnally, I have no need for this. I just check that the build phase is successful (in XCode/Android Studio or Terminal), and app install was successfull, to know that my native code is up to date