# Android Studio - Prompt before launching Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way on Android Studio to prompt the user before launching the Emulator ?

Sometimes I forget to plug my physical device, or it gets undetected for some reason.

Then when I click on run app, and forget to check the selected device, it auto launches the first set-up emulator.
This is annoying as it takes some time to stop the launching process.

A dialog prompting if I want to start an emulator would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not something instantly available, but still can be achieved by multiple steps,

- Create a gradle task that finds connected devices  [gradle task](https://gist.github.com/nuald/6b0408cf23039631b7db76347d405419)
- Execute this above task before generating build by combining with this method [Before build task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532415/execute-task-before-android-gradle-build)